# Posterior values for likelihood larger than 1

Tags: self-study, likelihood

I have a data set that has a random outlier. I'm trying to find the probability that the outlier was caused by human error or a cat walking on the keyboard.

I've created two hypothesis.

Null hypothesis: The outlier was caused by the cat

Alternative hypothesis: The outlier was caused by human error

Prior: (H0) = 0.4
Prior: (H1) = 0.6

To find n and k we can assume two things. Given the statement in the question given to us:
“this statistician has a cat which sometimes presses its paw on the keyboard when no-one is looking”

We can assume that 3/10 times the cat has had its paw on the keyboard. (Taking the value 3 from the word "sometimes").

Finding likelihoods:

P(X|H0)

> (factorial(10)/factorial(3))*0.4^3*(1-0.4)^10-3
>   [1] 231.0476

P(X|H1)

> (factorial(10)/factorial(7))*0.6^7*(1-0.6)^10-7
>   [1] -6.997887

Prior * likelihood

> 231.0476*0.4
>   [1] 92.41904
>
> -6.997887*0.6
>   [1] -4.198732

Sum:

> 92.41904+-4.198732
>   [1] 88.22031

Finding posterior probabilities:

H0: 92.41904/88.22031 = 1.04759

H1: -4.198732/88.22031 =-0.04759371

Given that my posterior probabilities are far too high/low means that I have calculated wrong.

Where did I go wrong as I can't see the mistake my self.

Comment: 1. "To find $n$ and $k$" but have not defined $n$ and $k$ and have given no explanation for the expressions $P(X \mid H_1)$ and $P(X \mid H_0)$ (which look like there is something strange going on, the prior should not be substituted into the likelihood. 2. Hint:  $P(X \mid H_1)$ should be a probability - something goes wrong in the way you evaluate the expression since you get a negative value

Answer (score 0):

So I've found my mistake.

Finding likelihoods:

P(X|H0)

> (factorial(10)/factorial(3))*0.4^3*(1-0.4)^7
>   [1] 1083.554

P(X|H1)

> (factorial(10)/factorial(7))*0.6^7*(1-0.6)^3
>   [1] 1.289945

Prior * likelihood

> 0.4*1083.554
>   [1] 433.4216
>
> 0.6*1.289945
>   [1] 0.773967

Sum:

> 433.4216+0.773967
>   [1] 434.1956

Posterior probabilities:

H0:

> 433.4216/434.1956
>   [1] 0.9982174

H1:

> 0.773967/434.1956
>   [1] 0.001782531

When multiplying to find likelihood values, i had input the wrong numbers